# Refresh token with JwtAuthProviderReader

Tags: servicestack, refresh-token

I'm wondering the best pratice to use `refresh-token` with `JwtAuthProviderReader`. At the moment when my *jwt* expires I send a request `/access-token` to get a new one.

```
 var jwt = authClient.Send(new GetAccessToken() {RefreshToken = Request.GetCookieValue("ss-refreshtok") }).AccessToken;
            Response.SetCookie(new Cookie()
            {
                Path = "/",
                Name = "ss-tok",
                Value = jwt
            });
```

My problem is I get *"Token has expired"* even though I already set the new *jwt* to the cookie. I have to refresh the page a few time before it's valid...

Here is my *Authenticate Service* :

```
   public class AuthenticationHandler: Service
   {
    private readonly JsonServiceClient authClient;
    public AuthenticationHandler()
    {
        authClient = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost/authentication/");
    }
    [Authenticate]
    public GetAuthenticationContextResponse Get(GetAuthenticationContext request)
    {

        var authSession = this.SessionAs<MyAbaxAuthSession>();
        return new GetAuthenticationContextResponse
        {
            CustomerId = authSession.CustomerId,
            UserId = int.Parse(authSession.UserAuthId)
        };
    }

    public UserAuthenticateResponse Post(UserAuthenticate request)
    {

        var response = authClient.Send(new Authenticate
        {
            provider = "credentials",
            UserName = request.UserName,
            Password = request.Password,
            UseTokenCookie = true
        });
        Response.SetCookie(new Cookie()
        {
            Path = "/",
            Name = "ss-tok",
            Value = response.BearerToken
        });

        Response.SetCookie(new Cookie()
        {
            Path = "/",
            Name = "ss-refreshtok",
            Value = response.RefreshToken
        });
        return new UserAuthenticateResponse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [JWT docs](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#refresh-tokens) on how to access your JWT RefreshToken, i.e. It's returned in `RefreshToken` property after a successful Authentication:

```
var response = client.Post(new Authenticate {
    provider = "credentials",
    UserName = userName,
    Password = password,
});

var jwtToken = response.BearerToken;
var refreshToken = response.RefreshToken;
```